# How to append attribute property to const values

Tags: c#

Consider below code:

```
[Category("USER")]
public class Permissions 
{
    public const string Create= "USER-CREATE";

    public const string Edit= "USER-EDIT";
    .
    .
}
```

I want to remove `USER-` part from const values because i specify it by `Category` attribute. In this case is there a way to get `USER-CREATE` value when i call `Permissions.Create`? If not, how to achieve same functionality with another approach?

**Edit**

I have to use const values because i will use with attribute.

For example : `[Attribute(Permissions.Create)]`

**Edit for my real case**

New code after @HimBromBeere suggest

```
[Permissions(Modules.Administration, HomePermissions.Category)]
public class UserPermissions 
{
    private const string Category = "USER";

    private const string Prefix = Modules.Administration + "-" + Category + "-"; 

    public const string Create = Prefix + "CREATE"; 
    public const string Edit = Prefix + "EDIT";
}
```

Comment: You can´t change a `const` value, that´s why it´s called a constant. But I´m not sure what exactly you want. You want t remove `"USER"` from the constant but still get `"USER-CREATE"` when *accessing* that constant? You would have to concatenate the categories name (read from the attribute) with the `const` which sounds bit overkill to me.

Comment: If you have constant values that are intended to be referenced from other assemblies then it's best-practice to use `static readonly` because if you use `const` then the value might be inlined during compilation of the dependent assembly, which can result in unintended consequences. Only use `public const` *if you really need to* (e.g. for use in Attribute constructors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a private `const` within your `Permissions`-class which you add to your actual constants.

```
[Category("USER")]
public class Permissions 
{
    private const string KEYWORD = "USER";

    public const string Create= KEYWORD + "-CREATE";    
    public const string Edit= KEYWORD + "-EDIT";
}
```

This isn´t exactly what you want but avoids at least *some* of the duplications. However you still need the `"USER"` value twice, once within the attribute and once within the private `const`. Avoiding this would need the attribute to be evaluated which is a runtime-operation and this can´t be used in your scenario.

EDIT: You could even replace the very first line by this:

```
[Category(Permissions.KEYWORD)]
```

Now all duplications of the same string are gone.

Comment: I updated question based on your suggestion. As you see, it is not readable but it seems there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You absoulutely can't do this. Most of the time, your constant values will be inlined by compiler in compile-time.

Instead, use **static readonly** qualifier. You can freely change it's value through reflection.

Another solution will be using **aspects**. For example you can see how it done in PostSharp. Basicaly it will postprocess your binaries and inject code into them.

Comment: Why use a `readonly` member and than change it using reflection? Either be strict and don´t change it (that´s what `readonly` is for) or mutable without any modifier, in this case you won´t need reflection to set the value.

Comment: From design point of view, I totaly agree with you. But I think he had no choise but do it this way.